# AAS Tabular Cube Refresh

Tags: azure, powerbi, ssas-tabular

I'm new to Azure Analysis Service and i have few question(s)

1. Whenever we do Full refresh/process AAS tabular cube, does that mean at same time Power-BI reports will become blank.
2. Will end user be able to view data in PBI report at the time of full Cube refresh?
3. Is it Truncate and reload of data, whenever we process AAS cube

Please let me know.

Thanks! in advance

Answer (score 2):

No, the Process Full brings the new data with database connection and refresh the tables beneath the tabular Cube. This will not function as Truncate and reload.

If you are selecting the Process Clear (From SSMS Analysis Server Engine) then the Power BI reports will show blank reports until you again process full.